# This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used. FLUTTER Iterate over a map inside a list

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a ToggleButtons for a menu options, in this part I'm trying to get a buttom where the customer can choose what type of milk the would like. So I have a map of the kinds of milk depending of the name of the milk and their prices. I'm trying to iterate over the map to get the name of the Milks (the map is inside of a List)

```
> class ToggleButtonsLeche extends StatefulWidget {
  final Drink drink;
  const ToggleButtonsLeche({Key? key, required this.drink}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ToggleButtonsLeche> createState() => _ToggleButtonsLecheState();
}

class _ToggleButtonsLecheState extends State<ToggleButtonsLeche> {
  List<bool> _isSelected = [true, false, false];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<BubbleTeaShop>(builder: (context, value, child) =>
        SafeArea(child: Column(
      children: [
        ToggleButtons(
            children: <Widget>[
              value.tiposdeLeche.forEach((element) => Text(element.tipodeLeche)
)
            ],
            isSelected: _isSelected)
      ],
    )
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error is in "forEach" it says "This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used. (Documentation)  Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void." Please help and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` is a void function. You can use `.map`.

```dart
...value.tiposdeLeche.map((element) => Text(element.tipodeLeche),
```

More about [spreed operators](https://dart.dev/language/collections#operators)

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)